# Add preprocessor definition only for Release build in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, qt-creator, qmake

I want to define QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT for Release build, but I couldn't find where to add it.

I need the preprocessor definition to be Release-specific, i.e. it should affect the Release build, **but not the Debug build**.

I'm looking for the equivalent of this (it's in Visual Studio):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your project file:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    #This is a release build
    DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
} else {
    #This is a debug build
}
```

Note that CONFIG can contain both "release" as well as "debug". Only the last is effective, which is what the above check does. This is explained here:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-function-reference.html#config-config